# Selecionar classe vinda de load

Tags: jquery, html, load

Tenho uma página que é carregada pela função ***load*** do ***jQuery*** conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
  $('#result').load('listar.php');
</script>
```

Nessa página **`listar.php`** tenho uma listagem de dados vinda do banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $linha->nome; ?></td>
  <td>
    <button class="ident" value="<?php echo $linha->id; ?>">Mostrar ID</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

O problema é que eu não consigo selecionar essa classe `ident`  do **`<button>`** pelo ***jQuery*** para pegar o **id**.

Eu queria pelo menos fazer isso:

```
$('.ident').click(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Como resolver esse problema? O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de tudo: não pesquisarei fontes para embasar o que direi.

Primeiramente:

*Eu queria pelo menos fazer isso:*

```
$('.ident').click(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Isso resolveria:

```
$('body').on("click", ".ident", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

*Como resolver esse problema?*

O "seletor base" para o evento, já deve estar carregado na tela no momento em que você adiciona o listener, portanto, basta fazer um bind de evento a um elemento que já esteja na tela e utilizar dos parâmetros da função para fazer uma sub-seleção. (melhor explicado a seguir)

*O que estou fazendo errado?*

Você está adicionando um listener a um elemento que ainda não está presente no DOM no momento da execução.

#### Explicações:

Quando você adiciona um evento via JavaScript, você está atribuindo uma ação a um determinado elemento. Caso um novo elemento, mesmo que com o mesmo seletor, seja inserido no DOM após a execução desse código, ele não estará escutando esse evento.

No caso, você adicionou um evento a classe `.ident`, porém, só os elementos com a classe `ident` que **já estivessem no DOM** na hora da execução do código estariam bindados a ele.

#### Por quê utilizar `$('body').on('click', '.ident', function(){});` resolve?

Neste caso, o evento de click está sendo adicionado ao elemento **body**, que já está no DOM no momento de execução, o que o jQuery está fazendo por trás neste caso, é basicamente: "após o clique dentro do elemento **body**, verifica se foi no elemento que tem uma classe `ident`". Desta maneira, o evento está vinculado ao body, e não ao elemento com a classe `ident`, o jQuery apenas confirma que o elemento clicado possui a classe desejada, ele não mantém nenhum evento bindado a classe ou outro elemento (além do body) em específico.

Comment: Sua resposta está muito boa, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Use o evento `.on()`:

```
$("body").on("click",".ident",function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: O primeiro código não funciona. Edite sua resposta e coloque apenas o segundo que funciona. Ele tem a função do `.delegate()`que foi descontinuado. Quando um elemento é adicionado dinamicamente na página, o segundo código funciona.